# My ReportViewer doesn't show anything

Tags: c#, rdlc

I am trying to make report at Windows Application using C# in ViStud 2010.
I read the tutorial at http://cybarlab.com/create-rdlc-report and my ReportViewer doesn't show anything. i attach my code at button that shows report.

```
    DataSet1TableAdapters.contohReportTableAdapter ta = new DataSet1TableAdapters.contohReportTableAdapter();
            DataSet1.contohReportDataTable dt = new DataSet1.contohReportDataTable();
            ta.Fill(dt, Decimal.Parse(textBox1.Text), Decimal.Parse(textBox2.Text));
            ReportDataSource rds = new ReportDataSource();
            rds.Name = "DataSet1";
            rds.Value = dt;

            ReportParameter rp1 = new ReportParameter("pnCBALmin", textBox1.Text.ToString());
            ReportParameter rp2 = new ReportParameter("pnCBALmax", textBox2.Text.ToString());

            //var reportStream = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream("Report1.rdlc");
            //reportViewer1.LocalReport.LoadReportDefinition(reportStream);

            reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
            reportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = "Report1.rdlc";
            reportViewer1.LocalReport.SetParameters(new ReportParameter[] { rp1, rp2 });
            reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rds);
            reportViewer1.LocalReport.Refresh();
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: Can you look into the SSRS log for verbose information for that request?

Comment: Can't find the log. because the the last log timestamps is at 06_01_2014, and i run my report app at 25 June 2014